# Jetpack compose: How to implement navigation in Modal Bottom sheet with animation, Nested navigation and allow viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

So basically I have an app that has one screen and three modal bottom sheets. I need a navigation infrastructure that helps me navigate between multiple bottom sheets in my app.
It should have transition animations, support for ViewModel, and Nested and independent navigation.

I need a very easy-to-implement guide as I am new to Compose.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the android doc for view model integration ([view model doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel)), and if you need additional dependency injection, you can take a look at Koin of Hilt libs.

Same things with navigation, you can use a NavHost coupled with a nav controller to navigate between screens or dialog, [navigation doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation). If you need to navigate to bottom sheet, or use animation for navigation, accompanist provide two simple libs for that [navigation animation](https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-animation/) and [navigation material](https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-material/).

And nested navigation is supported by default in the navigation libs, with the "navigation" block inside the NavHost DSL.

For a guide on how to use navigation and view model, you can check this : [navigation with view model](https://proandroiddev.com/jetpack-compose-navigation-architecture-with-viewmodels-1de467f19e1c)

If you want a really short and simple example, you will end up with something similar to that :

```
// In your MainActivity, inside a Scaffold or something like that, it will be your root composable
val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = "home",
) {
    // Main navigation graph
    composable("home") { HomeScreenComposable() }
    bottomSheet("my_dialog") { MyDialogComposable() }

    // Nested navigation graph
    navigation(
        startDestination = "nested_home",
        route = "nested_navigation_graph"
    ) { 
        bottomSheet("my_nested_dialog") { MyNestedDialogComposable() }
    }
}

@Composable    
fun HomeScreenComposable(viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel()) {
    // Your view goes here, and you can access the view model directly
}

// And if you need to navigate to a dialog or another composable
navController.navigate("my_dialog")
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and insightful answer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Where can i find the 'bottomSheet' extension for NavGraphBuilder ? is this an official one? or a custom implementation?

Comment: @MarlonLópez 
https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-material/
I have successfully implemented bottom sheet destinations this way.